# Error when using tabular: `[chktex] 44: User Regex`

Tags: tables

I'm trying to make a table, but certain lines keep giving me the error `% [chktex] 44: User Regex`. Here's my MWE, with comments showing which lines give the error:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ c | c | c | c | c } % [chktex] 44: User Regex
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline % [chktex] 44: User Regex
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Any idea what's going on? I've been using tables for some time now, and I've never had an error like this.

Comment: You are only showing a fragment of the message which is `Warning 44 in dd907.tex line 7: User Regex: -2:Use \toprule, midrule, or \bottom rule from booktabs.`  This seems rather agressive advice, I would silence that warning. booktabs is a fine package but warning about every use of hline seems excessive

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's the only part of the message that I can see. Also, what are they asking me to do in that full message, anyway?

Comment: are you running in some editor that hides the terminal? it is saying to replace `\hline` by `\toprule` from booktabs package (but then you would have to remove all `|` vertical rules as well, but this claims to be a user-added extra regex, so i suspect something is wrong

Comment: Addendum to David's comment: It seems you (or *they* whoever they are) are using [`chktex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/chktex) to evaluate not only the syntactical correctness but also the typography of your document.  See the [`chktex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/chktex/ChkTeX.pdf) for more information about it and how to use it.

Comment: this check for not using booktabs is in the system wide chktex config /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/chktex/chktexrc (and has been for some years it seems)